# Data range picker to select start and end dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am looking for a date range picker in which first click is to select a start date, the calendar is then refreshed and second click is to select an end date. All date ranger picker i am finding has two calendars with start and end dates to select at the same time.

Has anyone done anything like that.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Owais you can use jQuery Picker 

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/917/

try this link.
Thank you

Comment: Thanks but i need one datepicker which selects the start date and refreshes to select the end date

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-moment-picker take a look here

Comment: Post with similar problem with some nice solutions. [Javascript Date Range Picker - Single Calendar for Range Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770018/javascript-date-range-picker-single-calendar-for-range-selection)

Comment: Use simple https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ui-bootstrap-tpls datepicker
1. When you select the first date save it in a different variable then your model.
2. Refresh the calendar using the help from https://gist.github.com/cgmartin/3daa01f910601ced9cd3
3. use the saved date to highlight the calendar using customneClass method provided
4. select the new date and use it as end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using react-day-picker and it's highly customizable. Or try of airbnb which is lil bit heavy and consumes higher CPU

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this.

```js
 $( function() {
       $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
       
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $("#toDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $( "#toDate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#fromDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>From: <input type="text" id="fromDate"></p>
<p>To: <input type="text" id="toDate"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please check i guess one of these method would help you ,

Note : I am clueless whether posting a third party link is prohibited on stackoverflow , if so please let me know to remove the link below,

http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples

Comment: Thanks but i need one datepicker which selects the start date and refreshes to select the end date